# long json string returns err400 while shorter string works fine

Tags: php, ajax, json, continuous-integration

i'm trying to pass a json string from client to server, i have an array which is JSON.stringify-ed and then sent to server in a url which looks like this:

> http://localhost/sublimation/index.php/index/imgCreate/{"name":"pillow.png","element":"basketball-2.png","elAngle":0,"elTop":78,"elLeft":117,"elHeight":90,"elWidth":90,"captionA":"","capAR":0,"capAG":200,"capAB":200,"capATop":112,"capALeft":141,"capASize":12,"captionB":"","capBR":0,"capBG":200,"capBB":200,"capBTop":112,"capBLeft":141,"capBSize":12,"photo":"#","picTop":0,"picLeft":0,"picHeight":20,"picWidth":110,"picAngle":0}

now that returns an error 400 msg:

> HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

the only way i've managed to get it working was by cutting short the string, anything else failed.
as it looks json is not the most popular thing cause i didn't manage to find anything even remotely helpful on google.

does anyone have an idea?

tnx,
Ido

EDIT!!;
I've edited the code according to recommendations this is what i'm getting now: (still the same error)

> POST http://localhost/sublimation/index.php%2Findex%2FimgCreate%2F%7B%22name%22%3A%22pillow.png%22%2C%22element%22%3A%22amaut2.png%22%2C%22elAngle%22%3A0%2C%22elTop%22%3A34%2C%22elLeft%22%3A124%2C%22elHeight%22%3A90%2C%22elWidth%22%3A90%2C%22captionA%22%3A%22%22%2C%22capAR%22%3A%220%22%2C%22capAG%22%3A%22%200%22%2C%22capAB%22%3A%22%200%22%2C%22capATop%22%3A112%2C%22capALeft%22%3A141%2C%22capASize%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22captionB%22%3A%22%22%2C%22capBR%22%3A%220%22%2C%22capBG%22%3A%22%200%22%2C%22capBB%22%3A%22%200%22%2C%22capBTop%22%3A112%2C%22capBLeft%22%3A141%2C%22capBSize%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22photo%22%3A%22%23%22%2C%22picTop%22%3A0%2C%22picLeft%22%3A0%2C%22picHeight%22%3A20%2C%22picWidth%22%3A110%2C%22picAngle%22%3A0%7D 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: JSON is very popular, so try to get rid of that misconception as soon as you can.

Comment: When we said POST is the way to go, we meant that you post to http://localhost/sublimation/index.php and transmit all the parameters in the message body, not the URL. That URL is 720 chars long, which is not so much (works fine with my local Apache), but might already be too much for some webservers. The point of using POST is to keep the URL short.

Comment: that's what i'm doing. my code now is:

var data_string = JSON.stringify(data);
 url = "index.php/index/imgCreate/"+data_string;
 url = encodeURIComponent(url);

when data is a string and it still shows bad request. the code that i edited in the bottom part of my question is from the console and not the URL

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not a valid URL even if it were shorter. Characters like ", {, }, # and maybe : are disallowed in the path segment of the URL. You have to URI-secape them (" becomes %22 and so on). Maybe your browser did that automatically for you, and the resulting URL hit a length limit of the webserver which then returned the 400.

Using POST requests should solve the problem. You can transfer much more data there than in a URL.

Comment: POST is definitely the way you want to transmit json.

Comment: the url as you see it is after i changes it back from the %22 and etc. to make it more readable, i will try to post the data, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your json, because you have some special chars in json that interact if they are in url. [This](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) could help or give a clue.

Problem also could be with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sending your JSON by GET instead of POST. Too long of a GET will cause errors, and is susceptible to problems. Encoding your JSON string will help as well.